# How to get node neighbors by using recursion?

Tags: python, recursion, networkx

I very new with recursion function and i try to get node neighbors in graph by using recursion function and graph is look like this.

[image]

The Sequence that i want to get neighbors of each node in this graph.

First, get neighbors of first tree node on the top.

```
sub_node = [
             [D, E, F], #A neighbors
             [F, G, H], #B neighbors
             [H, I],    #C neighbors
            ]
```

**Here is my problem**

Next, get neighbors of previous neighbors and the order to get node neighbors is do with first index of all list first (list in `sub_node`), then do with the next index of all list again until out of index.
if do with `sub_node` will have the output like this.

```
sub_node = [ 
             #first
             [D, E, F], #A neighbors
             [F, G, H], #B neighbors
             [H, I],    #C neighbors

             #second --> do with first index in tree list above
             [J, K],    #D neighbors
             [L],       #F neighbors
             [L],       #H neighbors

             # --> second index
             [K, L], #E neighbors
             [G],    #L neighbors
             [M],    #I neighbors

             # --> third index
             [L], #F neighbors
             [L], #H neighbors

            ]
```

This is my code, and graph libraries that i using is NetworkX.
In my function and it much identify initail node first.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edges_from([('A', 'D'), ('A', 'E'), ('A', 'F'), 
                ('B', 'F'), ('B', 'G'), ('B', 'H'), 
                ('C', 'H'), ('C', 'I'), 
                ('D', 'J'), ('D', 'K'), 
                ('E', 'K'), ('E', 'L'), 
                ('F', 'L'), 
                ('G', 'L'), 
                ('H', 'L'), 
                ('I', 'M')
                ])


def get_neighbors(G, initial_node):
    sub_node = []
    for n in initial_node:
        sub_node.append(list(nx.neighbors(G, n)))


initial_node = ['A', 'B', 'C'] #identify initial node first.
get_neighbors(G, initial_node)
```

Now i can do only this part.

```
sub_node = [
             [D, E, F], #A neighbors
             [F, G, H], #B neighbors
             [H, I],    #C neighbors
            ]
```

And i really don't known how to do the rest past and using recursion function.

Comment: Why are you doing this using recursion?  A simple iteration through the edge list will produce this table.  Also, why are you building a neighbors list, when networkx can supply the information on request.?

Comment: The first one under "Here is my problem" is the desired output? That is a peculiar format. For " # --> second index"  did you mix up G and L? And I assume either you want children specifically or just not any nodes from an higher layer because your mid level nodes don't have the higher level ones in their list? And is the grouping of first child of each then second child of each a desired outcome or just how you happened to order them?

Answer (score 0):

This method doesn't use recursion, but I think your best bet would be to keep track of the nodes you know about, the nodes you've already checked, and iterate through the nodes you know about but haven't checked yet.

```py
import networkx as nx

# initially setting up the graph
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([('A', 'D'), ('A', 'E'), ('A', 'F'), 
                ('B', 'F'), ('B', 'G'), ('B', 'H'), 
                ('C', 'H'), ('C', 'I'), 
                ('D', 'J'), ('D', 'K'), 
                ('E', 'K'), ('E', 'L'), 
                ('F', 'L'), 
                ('G', 'L'), 
                ('H', 'L'), 
                ('I', 'M')
                ])

current_nodes = set(['A', 'B', 'C'])  # our list of known nodes
checked_nodes = set()  # our list of checked nodes

node_neighbors = {}
while len(current_nodes - checked_nodes) > 0:
    # first, randomly select a new node that we know about AND haven't already checked:
    current_node = (current_nodes - checked_nodes).pop()
    # get the neighbors of the node as unique elements:
    neighbors = set(nx.neighbors(G, current_node))

    # add any results we don't already know about to our list of known nodes:
    current_nodes |= neighbors  
    # save our results for this node:
    node_neighbors[current_node] = neighbors
    # finally, mark that we checked the node so we don't check it again:
    checked_nodes.add(current_node)

print(node_neighbors)
# {'C': {'H', 'I'}, 'H': {'C', 'B', 'L'}, 'B': {'G', 'F', 'H'}, 'L': {'G', 'F', 'E', 'H'}, 'A': {'F', 'E', 'D'}, 'D': {'A', 'K', 'J'}, 'J': {'D'}, 'K': {'E', 'D'}, 'G': {'B', 'L'}, 'F': {'B', 'A', 'L'}, 'E': {'A', 'K', 'L'}, 'I': {'M', 'C'}, 'M': {'I'}}
```